# How it is possible to convert LaTeX document to Word (docx file) with all cross-references and labels for images and equations, tables by Pandoc?

Tags: latex, label, docx, pandoc, cross-reference

I have a tex-file obtained originally from RStudio with bookdown. The original set of Rmd-files were deleted by accident.
So I need to convert below minimized correct tex-file to Word (docx file extension):

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Simple document},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% Avoid problems with \sout in headers with hyperref
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand{\sout}{}}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Simple document}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
}
\hypertarget{format}{%
\section{Format}\label{format}}

Read \ref{format} for details.

Or read \protect\hyperlink{format}{format}.

Formatting:

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  sup-script or power - x\textsuperscript{2} ;
\item
  sub-script - y\textsubscript{3} ;
\item
  strike through - \sout{strike through} ;
\item
  term -- definition ;
\item
  long term --- long definition .
\end{itemize}

Here comes \textbf{footnote} \footnote{Footnote text} with its contents.

Image with caption, see \ref{fig:image}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{\label{fig:image} Image}
\end{figure}

Labeled table is below, see table \ref{tab:table}.

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{\label{tab:table}\\
My table}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\textbf{Col 1 header} & \textbf{Col 2 header} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\endhead
r1c1 & r1c2 \\
r2c1 & r2c2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

Inline: \(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\).

Block:

\[ E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \]

Labeled, see \eqref{eq:eq}:

\begin{equation}
f\left(k\right) =\binom{n}{k} p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n k}
\label{eq:eq}
\end{equation}

See LaTeX \autocite{latex} site for details.

Code is below, see \ref{exm:code}:

\begin{example}
\protect\hypertarget{exm:code}{}{\label{exm:code} }Hello world
\end{example}

\begin{verbatim}
int main(){
  return 0;
}
\end{verbatim}

\hypertarget{references}{%
\section*{References}\label{references}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I try to convert it to docx using pandoc (2.16.1 version) command below:

`pandoc simple.tex --to docx+native_numbering --output simple.docx --table-of-contents --toc-depth 5 --number-sections --citeproc --verbose --csl ieee.csl`

(In the above command ieee.csl was downloaded [from Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/styles/ieee)).

I get

[image: Pandoc Latex to docx]

and I see many strange things:

- `[fig:image]` along with Figure with number;
- `[tab:table]` along with Table with number;
- `[eq:eq]` instead of equation number;
- `[exm:code]` instead of example number.

Is it possible to replace (or suppress them for Figure and Table) above strange `[…]` fields by correct numbers and links using Pandoc to get correct docx output?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported by plain pandoc, but you can use filters to get the numbering back. E.g., the [resolve-references.lua](https://github.com/openjournals/inara/blob/main/data/filters/resolve-references.lua) filter in the OpenJournals "Inara" project does something comparable. You may have to adjust and extend it to fully suit your requirements.

Comment: Disclosure: I'm the author of that filter. I would be willing to implement some (smallish) feature requests.

Comment: This is better than nothing, but running `pandoc simple.tex --to docx --output simple-pandoc.docx --table-of-contents --toc-depth 5 --number-sections --citeproc --verbose --csl ieee.csl --lua-filter resolve-references.lua` solves the problem only partially (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsSxK.png), yellow highlight is mine). Thanks for idea, I'll search on GitHub for lua-filters deeper.

Comment: This seems to be a 8 year anniversary of https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/813 .

Comment: Equations should work better now.